# Line above wrapfig has too much spacing

Tags: spacing, wrapfig

I have a very short sentence in my text above a **wrapfig**. The text above it has an awful spacing. I've tried to solve my problem in three different ways, but I was looking for a general solution, since I've encountered this problem several times.

I would like to have something like the 3rd one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is a brief sentence without anything.
\begin{wrapfigure}[32]{l}{8cm}
    \includegraphics[draft]{dorf.jpg} \caption{Wrapfig Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage

This is a brief sentence with \texttt{\textbackslash newline}.\newline
\begin{wrapfigure}[32]{l}{8cm}
    \includegraphics[draft]{dorf.jpg} \caption{Wrapfig Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
%
% I'm looking for a similar solution
%
This is a brief sentence with \texttt{\textbackslash par}.
\begin{wrapfigure}[32]{l}{8cm}
    \includegraphics[draft]{dorf.jpg} \caption{Wrapfig Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\newline
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of my original code.]

I would like the short sentence to be nicely placed on the left and the wrapped text that starts from the image's upper right corner.

Thank You in advice.

Comment: You are forcing the underfull lines with `\newline` Also please add `[draft]` to `\includegraphics` so we don't get errors on missing image files

Comment: Well, yes. I was just trying around. `\par` wasn't a better solution

Comment: You could try `\hfill\null` in the end of the previous sentence... Before `\par` or `\newline` etc....

Comment: @koleygr it works, but unfortunately it does not solve the other problems I had before. It seems, that I always have to hard code, if I want to use wrapfig. Anyway thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing some artefacts of the `\lipsum` macro, If you start the following paragraph with normal text then it looks OK (or possibly with `\noindent` if you do not want the para indentation)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is a brief sentence without anything.

\begin{wrapfigure}[32]{l}{8cm}
    \includegraphics[width=222px, height=326px]{dorf.jpg} \caption{Wrapfig Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
Some normal words \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Or perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is a brief sentence without anything.

\begin{wrapfigure}[31]{l}{8cm}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \includegraphics[width=222px, height=326px]{dorf.jpg} \caption{Wrapfig Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent Some normal words \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've modified my preamble also to avoid that spacing You got before `Some normal words`. I want the text to start on the upper right corner of the image, I've posted the output of my document and this is fine to me. What I do not want is that spacing above

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure I understand your comment, the main thing I thought you were asking about is the stretched horizontal white space in the "brief sentence" if you are worried about the vertical space above the image, put `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` or similar at the start of the wrapfig.

Comment: Thank You! It works ! I combined your hint `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` and I added `\par` after the "brief sentence" and now I've obtained a nice output.